# Cloud Run on GKE Anthos - Hello world not working

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-anthos

I am trying to deploy a container using Cloud Run on GKE with Anthos enabled. I was following the codelab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-gke.

When I create the container in Google Console I see that pods are created but it gets stuck with status "Waiting for Load Balancer to be Ready" on the "Routing traffic" stage. I am including the output below of the events.

```
Status:
  Address:
    URL:  http://hello-run.default.svc.cluster.local
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2020-09-09T02:16:13Z
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        ConfigurationsReady
    Last Transition Time:        2020-09-09T02:16:14Z
    Message:                     Waiting for load balancer to be ready
    Reason:                      Uninitialized
    Status:                      Unknown
    Type:                        Ready
    Last Transition Time:        2020-09-09T02:16:14Z
    Message:                     Waiting for load balancer to be ready
    Reason:                      Uninitialized
    Status:                      Unknown
    Type:                        RoutesReady
  Latest Created Revision Name:  hello-run-00001-qaz
  Latest Ready Revision Name:    hello-run-00001-qaz
  Observed Generation:           1
  Traffic:
    Latest Revision:  true
    Percent:          100
    Revision Name:    hello-run-00001-qaz
  URL:                http://hello-run.default.example.com
Events:
  Type    Reason   Age    From                Message
  ----    ------   ----   ----                -------
  Normal  Created  7m59s  service-controller  Created Configuration "hello-run"
  Normal  Created  7m59s  service-controller  Created Route "hello-run"
```

Has anyone run into this situation ?

Comment: Can you share your node pool configuration?

Comment: Hi @Vulcan I just followed the same tutorial as you did and I could deploy the services correctly. Considering that, could you please edit your question and provide more details on which specific step have you stopped in? If you could also include any differences in names, cluster image, etc., that you might have take differently from the tutorial, it will help.